# KOPS initiates itself after EC2 instance start following a stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops

I have a EC2 instance which my KOPS cluster is running. I observed that when the instance is stopped and started another day, the cluster starts itself automatically.

Does it mean that when EC2 instance is stopped, it goes into a state like 'Hibernate' Or KOPS has its own mechanism - like disaster recovery - and resilience when the host machine is down and up ?

Answer (score 2):

Instances are just a normal part of the AWS infrastructure. When EBS is used for storage, data is not lost when instance is stopped, hence when you restart your instances they are brought up with the same state stored on EBS drives. This is not an explicit "hibernation" mechanism, nor is it a particularly specific feature of kops, it's just a regular data retention of data stored on AWS EBS.